# Extracting values that appear in URLs after a post in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have an app that I am trying to load test with JMeter, and I am unable to extract a value from an URL, that is generated after HTTP POST.

The app flow (simplified) goes something like this, with corresponding URLs:

1. Login: `http://host:port/login`
2. Go to Dashboard (HTTP GET): `http://host:port/dashboard`
3. Click "Create Content" (HTTP GET): `http://host:port/$string1/$string2=/create`
4. Enter data, click "Submit" (HTTP POST) now URL is: `http://host:port/$string1/$string2=/content/$string3`

`$string1`, `$string2` & `$string3` are randomly generated; `$string1` &  `$string2` are available in the body at the dashboard URL (which are easily extracted using regex); `$string3` however is returned *after* content is created. I need `$string3` at Step 4 above to view the newly created content, and proceed with next steps in my script.

I don't have access to the internals of the app or the server it is on.

Sanity check:

- Is this a chicken-egg situation?
- Or am I missing something in JMeter?
- Any way around this problem?

Comment: It there redirect at step 4 to the new URL after performing Submit via POST? If yes then you can possibly try to use `Follow Redirects` option of [HTTP request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request).

Comment: Thanks @AliesBelik, `Follow Redirects` is already checked. Any thing else I could look at?

Comment: Can you expand your question with more details about how is `$string3` returned after the content is generated? Is it returned using some JavaScript function or what?

Comment: @zorlem: After going back and forth with the developers of the app, `$string3` is generated using encryption methods and base64 encoded, and there is no way to know (so they tell me) ahead of time what the value of `$string3` is going to be. We ended up load testing another related portion of the app. Thanks for dropping in!

Comment: If this `$string3` can be used by the browser for submitting subsequent requests, and is provided by the server in an HTTP response, then it can be extracted and used by Jmeter as well.
Anyway, sorry you've had to resort to a workaround, good that's been an option. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume after you click "submit" it's a post request that will start the create content process, then get a redirect reply from the server. (you can verify if it's a redirect reply in tree view)

Uncheck the redirect option in Jmeter and add a regex extractor element to the same request.

Then extract the redirect URL with something like `Object moved to <a href="/(.+?)">here` and in the next HTTP request element you can use that extracted as variable to Path like `${string3}`!